# MariaDB ODBC drivers on Win10 cannto be added to ODBC Data Source Administrator

Tags: mariadb, odbc

I have managed this in the past on two separate machines. Now one machine has lost the DSNs and I cannot for the life of me add them back.

Uninstalled all MariaDB exes and MariaDB ODBC drivers.

Installed latest MariDB 10.5 and latest 32-bit MariaDB ODBC 3.1 drivers 3.1.9 (26/6/20)

Using ODBCad64 I am informed I am not administrator when I am (but this is not a huge problem, and other answers point to Office causing this).

I want to use 32bit drivers with VFP9 anyway, so usually run ODBCad32.exe as administrator, go to System DSNs and Add...

I can add any of the listed drivers except the MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver, which just shows a thinking-about-it cursor for a few seconds, then nothing, rather than the dialogue to choose the data source.
This behaviour occurs on User DSNs as well. On a separate Win10 machine I correctly get the next dialogue "Create a new Data Source to MariaDB" wizard, which I have had in the past on the problem machine. The problem machine will be the production database server, and has worked perfectly in the past, before losing the DSNs.
The other machine is development and bizarrely can still connect to the production machine, even though I uninstalled and reinstalled everything there and haven't setup DSNs there, and cannot see any existing ones. The development machine connects to MariaDB 10.05 (correct, just installed that on the production machine 10 minutes ago) using DRIVER={MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver};TCPIP=1;SERVER=;UID=root;PWD=*******;PORT=4306 (there is an existing service on 3306).

So the Driver appears to be working remotely, but I cannot add DSNs to use ODBC locally. What I can do is (locally) send the complete SQL connection string from VFP i.e. a DSN-less connection.
Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: You could run regedit.exe and have a look around `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC` to see if there appears to be any "junk" in the subkeys that might be interfering with adding a new DSN. Or, you could completely remove the MariaDB ODBC driver again and then check the registry to see if anything has been left behind.

Comment: Thanks! The two machines are identical in every subkey, except for the DSNs that correctly exist on one. Copying this DSN to the recalcitrant machine doesn't help - it doesn't show up in odbcad32 nor can it be connected in VFP.. Adding a test DSN for the Microsoft Text driver does work ok. I think I'll stick to using the complete connection string from VFP, although a level of indirection would be nice. Seeing as VFP is a database as well, storing and changing the ODBC parameters won't be too onerous compared to hard coding them into the source code. Thanks again.